# Azure - How to append new IP to SourceAddressPrefix for multiple Network Security Groups

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I reached an impas trying to update existent NSGs with a new IP.
The only way I found is by using **Set-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig**, but it is not possible to append IPs to **SourceAddressPrefix** list, only overwrite with a new list.

For example:

```
$ruleip=$item| Select-Object -Property SourceAddressPrefix,name,Priority
       
foreach( $ip in $ruleip)
    {
        if( $ip.SourceAddressPrefix -eq $requiredIp){
        
        $rec=Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $ng.Name
        
        Set-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig `
            -Name $ip.Name `
            -NetworkSecurityGroup $rec `
            **-SourceAddressPrefix ("172.22.0.0/17","172.23.0.0/17") `**
            -Protocol * `
            -Access Allow `
            -Direction Inbound `
            -DestinationAddressPrefix * `
            -SourcePortRange * `
            -DestinationPortRange * `
            -Priority $item.Priority
        Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -NetworkSecurityGroup $rec
    }
   }
```

I tried using System.Object input like :

```
-SourceAddressPrefix ($($item.SourceAddressPrefix),"17x.xx.x.x/xx")
```

But it throws an error:

```
Set-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'SourceAddressPrefix'. Specified method is not supported.
```

Does anyone know an alternative?
Thank you!

Comment: You're creating an array that has 2 items - the first item is an array (i.e. the array object ```$item SourceAddressPrefix```) and the second is a string (your new address). Try ```( @($item.SourceAddressPrefix) + "17x.xx.x.x/xx" )``` instead - this will create an array containing the *items* in ```$item.SourceAddressPrefix``` followed by your new address.

Comment: That's it! Thanks so much!